# sharepoint null propagating operator in webparts ascx code

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part

I using null propagating operator in webparts ascx code but i getting below error:

> Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5.  Please use language version 6 or greater.

How can i use that?

This is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth1" Text='<%# ((Year)Container.DataItem).Months.Find(x=>x.MonthNum == "1")?.Value%>'runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use null propagating operator you need to use C#6.0 version. To enable it you need to check your project properties.

Steps taken to fix:

Open Project's Properties

Click Build

Click Advanced

Set Language Version to C# 6.0

Clean / Rebuild

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/70379)

Comment: @DikeshGandhi....thanks for comments,...it was supposed to be answer only, but may be it was not detailed enough...have modified accordingly....:)